# What would be the correct routes when finding a parent and then creating a child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I want to have a user search for a store and then select the store they want to use. It should go to a form which lets a user add a new price to that store like a comment to an article but instead I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PricesController#new

Couldn't find Store without an ID
```

These are my associations:

```
class User
  has_many :prices

class Store
  has_many :prices

class Price
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :store
```

So when a user selects a store it should go to `price/new` and know the ID of the store being used. Maybe something like:

```
<%= form_for @price, :url => create_price_store_path(@store) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Then the actions I'm using:

```
class PricesController

  def select_store
    # Find the store using sunspot search
    @search = Store.search do |s|
      s.fulltext params[:search] unless params[:search].blank?
      s.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
    @stores = @search.results
  end

  def new
    @store = Store.find(params[:id])
    @price = Price.new
  end
end
```

Then my routes so far:

```
resources :stores do
  member do
   post :create_price
  end
end

resources :prices do
  collection do
    get :select_store
  end
end
```

Why do I get this error? What should be corrected?

Comment: In your new action you probably won't have any ID in the params. But this code seems a bit messy to me. Why won't you use a combobox to select the store id on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think your routes are not set up correctly.

If you want to create a price, depending on a store (or do any other restful action), you should set up your routes like this:

resources :stores do
  resources :prices
end

So your `PricesController` will be reachable through this url:

```
stores/:store_id/prices/[:action/[:id]]
```

In your setup you're only saying, that your `PricesController` has a method named `create_price` which can be triggered via a POST request trhough `stores/:store_id/create_price`. But you don't have this method defined in your `PricesController` (at least not in the snippet you provided)

So if you're doing nested resources, as I've written above, you can have your `PricesController` as follows:

```
PricesController
  def new
    @store = Stores.find(params[:store_id])
    @price = @store.build   # this builds the Price object based on the store
  end

  def create
    # depending if your model uses `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
  end
end
```

Hope this is the explanation you're looking for :)

UPDATE:
What I forgot to mention was, if you want your `PricesController` to be accessible without a given store as well (since you wrote `resources :prices` above, I'm assuming you do), you need to check in your controller if a `:store_id` is given in the `params` hash, and if not do the stuff you want to do without a given store)